# How to fix "SPI_ERROR_UNCONNECTED" error while installing PL/Java on Postgresql-9.5

Tags: postgresql-9.5, pljava

I'm trying to install PL/Java on PostgreSQL-9.5. My current server is Ubuntu 16.04. My reference link to install PL/Java is the official website: https://tada.github.io/pljava/install/install.html

The build process for PL/Java, as described in the link https://tada.github.io/pljava/build/build.html is working fine.

When I run `mvn clean install` the output is: [maven output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4hhl.png)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PostgreSQL PL/Java ................................. SUCCESS [  1.049 s]
[INFO] PL/Java API ........................................ SUCCESS [  2.499 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend Java code .......................... SUCCESS [  1.574 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend native code ........................ SUCCESS [ 17.971 s]
[INFO] PL/Java Ant tasks .................................. SUCCESS [  0.179 s]
[INFO] PL/Java examples ................................... SUCCESS [  0.747 s]
[INFO] PL/Java packaging .................................. SUCCESS [  0.736 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.420 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-21T01:31:58-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/576M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the self-extracting installer JAR, the output is: [JAR Installer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI2wG.png)

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/libpljava-so-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.so as bytes
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as bytes
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava-api-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as bytes
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava-examples-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as bytes
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/pljava.control as lines (ASCII)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--unpackaged--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.2--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.1--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.1-BETA3--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.1-BETA2--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.1-BETA1--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.0--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.0-BETA3--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.0-BETA2--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pljava/pljava--1.5.0-BETA1--1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.sql as lines (UTF8)
```

I have explictly set libjvm_location as well: [libjvm_location set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEToi.png)

```
postgres=# alter system set pljava.libjvm_location to '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=#
```

When I run **CREATE EXTENSION pljava**, i get the following error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pljava;
ERROR:  java.sql.SQLException: SPI function SPI_prepare failed with error SPI_ERROR_UNCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 0):

Another old question, answering just so future visitors will find something.

In this question, the version of PL/Java being built was an unreleased version (1.6.0-SNAPSHOT) and simply didn't include the changes at that time to support PostgreSQL 9.5.

Snapshot versions, and anything built from the `master` (development) branch, are moving targets, might be far from release, not work, set your house on fire, etc. Recommended practice is to check [the releases page](https://github.com/tada/pljava/releases) and select a recent official release.

If it will be used on Ubuntu or Debian, rather than building from source, it's usually simpler to add [the PGDG `apt` repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) and simply `apt-get install postgresql-9.5-pljava` (or your PostgreSQL version in place of 9.5).